# eclim org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot create file, access denied: /path /to/my_project

Tags: java, eclipse, vim, eclim

- I installed eclim
- Opened eclimd(like as skript ./eclimd).
- Then tried create a new project in vim using command: 
  *:ProjectCreate /path/to/my_project -n java* and get this error.

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot create file, access
>   denied: /path /to/my_project. while executing command (port: 9091):
>   -editor vim -command project_create -f "/p ath/to/my_project" -n java

Can somebody know reason of this error in eclim and how to fix it?

Comment: Most likely your user doesn't have enough read-write permissions on /path /to/my_project

Comment: I tried sudo but not working have some idea to solve it?

Comment: What exactly did you try with sudo? I think you should reinstall eclim as sudo and use this as sudo as well